# Mobile Device (Android) Text Booster & CSS Issues

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, fonts

I'm building a website, which is (almost) mobile friendly, and after testing it on several devices, have found that things work well - Except for the fact that on my device, some of the text was bigger than it should have been after scaling.

I found that it was due to my device (Galaxy S4) having "Text Booster" function checked, which must detect larger amounts of text and resize it automatically to suit what it thinks is a more correct size.

Now this is fair enough, but I was hoping that I would be able to have control over the size of the font on various device widths using purely CSS.

**IMPORTANT** I'm finding that my "About Text" in the footer **isn't** affected by the booster, so I'm hoping that there is a way to prevent the main article text being resized, but does anyone know how?

Here is the relevant CSS that I'm using:

```
html{ // Sets the default font size
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #999999;
    cursor: default;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.aboutText{ // Holds the un-affected font 
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.result{ // Holds the text made bigger with Text Booster
    line-height: 18px;
    color: 606060;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="spaceInner"></div>
<div class="mainText">
    <div class="result">$post_article</div>
</div>

<div class="mainText">
    <div class="aboutImg"></div>
    <div class="aboutText"><?php echo $site_about; ?></div>
    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why one font scales down but the other one "boosts" up?

**UPDATE**

I have found that `float: left` prevents Text Booster from changing the font size. I can't use float on my main text area, so is there another alternative???

Comment: include your html part also

Comment: Added the HTML!!!